State-space representation of ARMA(2,2)
I need to write an ARMA(2,2) process in state-space form.
I don't know how to do it. I know that for the state-space representation I need two equations in the form
$$\xi_{t+1}=A\xi_t+Bv_{t+1}$$
$$y_t=C\xi_t$$
and on my book I read that $A=\begin{pmatrix}\phi_1 & \phi_2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, $v_{t+1}=\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon_{t+1}\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \theta_1 & \theta_2\end{pmatrix}$, but I am not able to define the vector $\xi_t$, which probably has elements which are linear combinations of $y$ and $\varepsilon$. I would like to keep these expressions from the book and just find the correct 3 elements of $\xi$.
Thank you to anyone who can help!!
